# When trying to build DisplayCandy, the terminal gives me this error

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

DisplayCandy is an animations framework for iOS. I'm trying to modify it (with the author's permission of course) to mimic the iOS 6.x animations on iOS 7.x/8.x. First off, I wanted to see if the original code worked on iOS 8.x, but this happened when running "make package" in terminal:

```
Making all in displaycandysettings...
Making all for bundle DisplayCandySettings...
 Copying resource directories into the bundle wrapper...
 Compiling DCSettingsListController.m...
 Linking bundle DisplayCandySettings...
 Stripping DisplayCandySettings...
 Signing DisplayCandySettings...
Making all for tweak DisplayCandy...
 Compiling DCFunctions.m...
DCFunctions.m:3:10: fatal error: 'GraphicsServices/GraphicsServices.h' file not
      found
#include <GraphicsServices/GraphicsServices.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [obj/DCFunctions.m.4c382f22.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [DisplayCandy.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

I have set the theos symlinks in both the project files and the files for the preference panel. The code is available [here](https://github.com/coolstar/displaycandy). I'm not the developer of the original tweak, but I am going to modify it to mimic the iOS 6 animations. How do I fix the error? It seems there's a file missing, but I don't know where I can obtain this file, nor do I know where I should put the file. I'm using a MacBook Pro on OS X 10.10.1, and am trying to deploy to an iPod touch 5th generation running iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really old framework you're dealing with there. `GraphicsServices` is part of the undocumented headers for iOS 3.x and 4.x. It originates from the https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks GitHub project.

Given the import path `GraphicsServices/GraphicsServices.h` you would need to put the `GraphicsServices` folder at the root level of your project to fix the compilation error.